# Is there a way to suppress the iOS App Store update indicator for a specific app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

*EDIT*

I don't know *why* somebody would want to do this! In fact it was a customer who claimed this *was* possible and I wanted to prove him wrong; and your reaction clearly show that it isn't true.

---

If I submit an update to an existing application on the Apple App Store, at some point, the iOS devices with previous versions will start showing an indicator that an update is available.
This badge that's shown on top of the app store application: can it be influenced? Is there a way to suppress it in case a new version has been submitted?
Some setting in info.plist maybe?

Comment: Nope. Why would you, anyways? The purpose of an update is to get your users to download it, no?

Comment: Highly doubtful; why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: and I don't think this questions is on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible what you want to do.
And, in my opinion, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to release a version of your app and not encourage people to install it? But in answer to your question, no.